# QuickFix configuration: What settings do I set to never attempt to login?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I have several instances of software that read a QF configuration file.  The default setting is to log in in the morning and out in the evening.

```
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=21:00:00
```

However,  I need one instance to run, but not log in.  How can I do this?  Do I need to override the default times ( if so, with what? ) or is there another field I can set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Session is setup by default when an initiator connects to an acceptor. The engine is so designed, [as FIX demands](http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/body_494965.html), that the first message is the Logon message. If any other message is sent before a logon message it will be discarded. If no logon happens before messages are transferred you will open up a can of worms. Anybody can set up a session and start doing whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want QF to never log in automatically you could try setting the StartTime and EndTime to the same value (but not 00:00:00). The other purpose of StartTime/EndTime is to automatically reset sequence numbers for each session time period. If you disable this, you might need to manually reset your sequence numbers each day. However, it's possible that QF will still reset the sequence numbers each day even with a zero-length session when the time crosses the session StartTime.

The other answer is incorrect. You can actually "send" messages before logging in. The engine will store those messages until the session is eventually initiated. The FIX engine's gap fill logic will then transmit the messages that were sent (to the engine) before the session was established through a proper log in.

Comment: Ok it is incorrect to say it is discarded, but see it from a real world viewpoint, why would you send messages before logging in ? What purpose does it solve when you send messages and you cannot get anything done ? And if I remember correctly you get a retun reject message from Quickfix when you send a message before logging in. From your answer it seems you have played around with QF to find out how to log automatically, but it is more of a hack then what QF is designed to do.

Comment: No, that's the default behavior (for most, if not all, commercial FIX engines).

Comment: To elaborate, session connections may drop temporarily during application operation. By storing messages while the connection is down, the application doesn't need to handle this directly. This is implemented using the same mechanism as message resend (gap fill) when a sequence number gap is detected.